# Minimal Desktop Indicator in Kubuntu is not showing

Tags: kubuntu, kde, indicator, widgets

I recently installed Minimal Desktop Indicator in my Kubuntu for instant desktop switching, but somehow It is not showing & taken an empty space in the Latte Panel.

[image: Check the Latte Panel Here]

Also, I have tried to add it directly on the desktop, but it doesn't show!

[image]

I have tried to add it by Add Widget from widget store & by local file also, but no changes. Also I have restarted the whole system after adding it.

Add widget from Widget Store:

[image: See the Image from Widgets Store]

[Got the local file from the Pling KDE Store](https://store.kde.org/p/1878511/)

Here is the Image from local file:

[image: Here is the Image from local file]